# Problema Angular.js con input al utilizar ng-model & ng-change en el mismo input

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un problema cuando intento utilizar un ng-model juntamente con un ng-change en un input me da el siguiente

```
error => Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!
```

Código

```
<div class="wn_row wn_row-collapse">
  <div class="wn_name">Sub-máscara de Rede</div>
  <div class="wn_value"> 
    <input type="text" class="wn_text" ng-model="lanConfPage.lanconn.dhcp_server.subnet" ng-change="lanConfPage.subnetChanged()">
   </div>
```

**En el controlador tengo el siguiente codigo. `lanConfPage` es el nombre del controlador**

```
constructor(netmapManager: NosNetmapManager, public chfBlockUI) {
    this.lanconn = <any>netmapManager.netmap.lanconns[0];
    this.bridgeMode = <any>netmapManager.netmap.bridge_mode;
    this.leaseTime = this.getLeaseTimeInMin();
  }

subnetChanged() : void {
    let message : string = "wwwww";
    document.getElementById("messageInfo").innerHTML = message;
  }

export var _chfMetadata: chf.core.PageComponentMeta = {
  name: 'chfLanConfPage',
  path: "/settings/lan_conf",
  menuTitleKey: 'menu.LAN',
  position: 2,
  parentId: 'settings',
  component: () => {
    return {
      controller: LanConfPage,
      controllerAs: 'lanConfPage',
      template: require('./chf-lan-conf-page.tpl.html'),
      bindToController: true
    }
  }
};
```

No entiendo cual es el problema. Muchas gracias

Comment: que versión de angular estás usando? la 2?

Comment: no no estoy utilizando la version 2 si no una version anterior

Comment: Imagino que estas usando TypeScript con Angular 1. Tu código está bien, estas seguro que es en ese fragmento donde se está produciendo el error? No tendrás otro `ng-change` en tu HTML?

Comment: si estoy utilizando TypeScript con Angular. Solo tengo un ng-change en la vista html